# Formula for 'No' Condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I am using the following to update items in a SharePoint List whenever an Excel workbook in a SharePoint Library is updated.

If the condition isn't met, meaning rather than updating existing data in the workbook the user added a new line item that doesn't meet the condition in the flow, what should I put in the 'No' action  so that the new item is added to the SharePoint List?

[image]

Edited Content:

I got it to the following. However, the 'No' statement creates multiples of the existing data on in the workbook to the List, rather than only adding the new item - which is eventually does create, multiple times.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new SharePoint list item in the No branch of the condition, then you need to use the SharePoint action "Create Item".

[image]

Enter the site and list and populate the item the same way you do for "Update item".

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I've updated my post based on your recommendation. Please review, thank you.

Comment: I've answered your question. You can't just edit it an add more issues to it. This isn't how this site works. You may want to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Accept the answer as explained in the [tour]. Then feel free to ask a new question about your next issue.